# Azure Devops pipeline App Center Task error: failed to load list of organizations

Tags: azure-devops

My pipeline is using the App Center Task to run UI tests in App Center. The problem is that the task returns the error "failed to load list of organizations".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in the pipeline is likely due to the wrong type of token being used to create the service connection.
There are two types of tokens, app level tokens and account level tokens. You need to use an account level token in the service connection.

You can create an account level token from here: https://appcenter.ms/settings/apitokens
Please ensure to generate one with full access, and create a new service connection with this token and link to it in the test task.